# How to change the landing image in strapi?

Tags: strapi

How to change this logo? I have changed the admin logo, top left logo. But not able to change this logo.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution, Add your custom image on the public folder with public/assets/images/logo_login.png

[image]